In C, is input = fgets(input,sizeof(input),*pt) a mistake?
Is it correct that in C programming when we pass the parameters pointer_to_string, sizeof_string and the stream for the fgets() function, we do not have to write back the return of the function to the pointer_to_array that was defined earlier/given as the parameter for fgets().
Why would that be a mistake?
char string_ofsize_ten[10];
string_ofsize_ten = fgets(string_ofsize_ten, 10, stdin);


No, you use the return value to test if the function succeeded, or to chain to another function – not to attempt to replace the argument you passed. The compiler should tell you that you cannot assign a value to an array identifier.

It's typically used as if (fgets(...) != NULL), or similar.

I also recommend that you use sizeof for the size of the array. But only if you have an actual array. If all you have is a pointer, you need to explicitly specify the size (which should have been passed to your function as an argument).

Note that if you use something like char *buffer = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE); (if (buffer == NULL) { …error… } buffer = fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, fp); and the file stream is empty, you've just written over the only pointer to the allocated memory and have created a memory leak.  Assigning the return value of fgets() is almost invariably a mistake.  With other functions such as scanf(), using int rc = scanf("…", …); can be valuable — it tells you how many successful conversions there were, and the value in rc could be EOF, 0, 1, or more (depending on the details in the ellipses).

Array expressions like array_ofsize_ten cannot be the target of an assignment; the language simply doesn't allow it.  fgets will write to the array as part of its operation, so you don't need to assign the result back to the original array.
The return value is mainly used to test if the operation succeeded; fgets will return NULL if it sees an EOF or error on the input stream before any characters:
if ( fgets( target, sizeof target, stream ) ) // implicit test against NULL
{
  // process target 
}
else if ( feof( stream ) )
{
  // handle EOF
}
else
{
  // handle I/O error
}

You could also pass that return value as an argument to another function that expects a char *:
printf( "%s\n", fgets( target, sizeof target, stream ) );

although this will blow up if fgets returns NULL, so it's not used that much.

Indeed the function fgets returns the passed to it pointer (if an array is used as an argument it is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element) as the first argument in case of a success. But you may not assign a pointer to an array as it is written in your code snippet
char string_ofsize_ten[10];
string_ofsize_ten = fgets(string_ofsize_ten, 10, stdin);

Arrays are non-modifiable lvalues.
Again pay attention to that in the call of the function fgets above the array used as an argument is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first argument.
The returned pointer is used to check whether a call of fgets was successfull or not as for example
while ( fgets(string_ofsize_ten, sizeof( string_ofsize_ten ), stdin) !=  NULL )
{
     string_ofsize_ten[ strcspn( string_ofsize_ten, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
     puts( string_ofsize_ten );
}

On the other hand, if for example instead of an array you are using a pointer to a dynamically allocated memory like
char *string_ofsize_ten = malloc( 10 );
string_ofsize_ten = fgets(string_ofsize_ten, 10, stdin);

then such a call of fgets can result in a memory leak if the function will return a null pointer because the address of the allocated memory will be lost due to the reassignment of the pointer by null.

Thanks, i read somewhere: you should error handle fgets with feof and ferror, but here you just used !=. What is the difference?

@plantpot When the function returns a null pointer it means that either there is no more data or an error occurred.  If you are not interesting what error occurred if it is indeed occurred then such a loop will output all records that were successfully read.

@plantpot be careful how you use feof(). Don't use it to control the loop, but to diagnose why an error occured.
